# How to do a Lucene search with Sitecore item with specific date?

Tags: .net, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

I've a Content item is Sitecore with the date field named 'EventDate'. I want to search those items with specific date using Lucene.Net.

Below is the code I've tried but i am not getting the result:

```
var index = SearchManager.GetIndex("event_search_index");   
var items = new List<EventDetailItem>();   
var eventDateString = eventDate.Year.ToString("D4") + eventDate.Month.ToString("D2") +  eventDate.Date.Day.ToString("D2");

using (var context = new IndexSearchContext(index))
{
    var searchTerm = new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("EventDate", eventDateString);    
    var query = new Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery(searchTerm);   
    var topFieldDocs = context.Searcher.Search(query, 1);    
    if (topFieldDocs != null) 
    {
        var scoreDocs = topFieldDocs.ScoreDocs;
        foreach (var scoreDoc in scoreDocs)
        {
            var doc = context.Searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc);
            var uriField = doc.GetField("_url");
            var itemUri = new Sitecore.Data.ItemUri(uriField.StringValue());
            var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(itemUri.ToDataUri());

            if (item == null) continue;

            var eventItem = new EventDetailItem(item);
            items.Add(eventItem);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you double-checked whether there's anything in your index? 
http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Index_Viewer.aspx is a very handy tool to check if there's anything in your index, and you can run your query using that as well to check if your query is wrong.

Comment: Do you use standard Sitecore datetime field for `EventDate`?

Comment: Yeah, i've double checked it. I have another method which takes a date range and returns the list of items. This method is working.

Comment: Yes Maras. I am using standard Sitecore Date field for EventDate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using standard **Sitecore** date field (switch to raw values view) so the date is stored as `yyyyMMddTHHmmss` string, e.g.:

```
20130418T140122
```

And then you use `TermQuery` with the first part of the query only, e.g.:

```
20130418
```

So you don't see any result as `TermQuery` matches exact field value.

You should either try `WildcardQuery` with `20130418*` or use `RangeQuery` starting from `20130418T000000` including this value and ending on `20130819T000000` excluding this value.

[Here you can find more information about troubleshooting Sitecore and Lucene problems.](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/troubleshooting-sitecore-lucene-search-and-indexing/)