# In Sitecore how to run a date range query using Lucene?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

I need to be able to run a date range query in Sitecore using Lucene and the newest `Sitecore.Search` framework.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I haven't been able to find a good example. I have Googled a bit and found bits and pieces here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find similar question here: [How to do a Lucene search with Sitecore item with specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082256/how-to-do-a-lucene-search-with-sitecore-item-with-specific-date)

Just treat those fields as a standard string fields and execute Range Query starting from e.g. **20130418T000000** including this value and ending on **20130819T000000**

This is a method which works for me:

```
    private static void CreateCreatedDatesQueryPart(BooleanQuery query, string createdFrom, string createdTo)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(createdFrom) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(createdTo))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createdFrom))
            {
                createdFrom = "000000t000000";
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(createdTo))
            {
                createdTo = "999999t999999";
            }
            query.Add(new TermRangeQuery("__created", createdFrom, createdTo, true, true), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        }
    }
```

[Here you can find more information about solving Sitecore and Lucene problems.](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/troubleshooting-sitecore-lucene-search-and-indexing/)

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  I followed that example and it didn't work.  It didn't return any results.

Comment: Which Sitecore version do you use? What type are the fields? Are you sure the fields are indexed and the items are indexed?

Comment: Sitecore 6.6 is the version.  The field is a Date field.  And yes the fields and items are indexed.  I am using Index Viewer to look at the index data.

Comment: Does your code looks similar to the method above? Are the values in the index viewer in the `YYYYMMDDTHHmmss` or `YYYYMMDD` format?

Comment: I had the same issue with date range searching in 6.6, the code worked in 6.4 so wondering if its linked to the Lucene.Net version change.

Comment: Ok.  I figured it out.  Apparently the field name needs to be in all lower case.  Once I did that it works!